# can i use ((TextField)selecteDOP.getEditor()).getText() in datepicker when retrieving values from database

Tags: mysql, sql, database, javafx

```
public DatePicker selecteDOP;
public Label label;

String dop = ((TextField)selecteDOP.getEditor()).getText();
String msg1 ="";

@FXML
public void purchases(ActionEvent event){
    msg1 = "First name   Last name   Username   Description  Code  Size  Cost  Quantity  Date of purchase\n";
    try{
        String qr = "SELECT j_fname,j_lname,username,description,code,size,cost,quantity,dop FROM jeff INNER JOIN purchase ON jeff.j_mail = purchase.username where dop='"+dop+"'";
        rs = st.executeQuery(qr);

        while (rs.next()){
            msg1 += rs.getString("j_fname")+"  "+rs.getString("j_lname")+"  "+rs.getString("username")+"   "+rs.getString("description")+"    "+rs.getString("code")+"  "+rs.getString("size")+"  "+rs.getString("cost")+"  "+rs.getString("quantity")+"   "+rs.getString("dop")+"\n";
        }
        label.setText(msg1);

    }catch (Exception e){
        System.out.println(e);
    }

}
```

I tried to retrieve data from database for a particular date that user select from datepicker but my code doesn't work.Can you suggest me how to overcome it

Comment: How are the values stored in the db? What's the type of the column? Using `PreparedStatement` and setting value via that object would most likely be simpler. Also what's wrong with retrieving the value inside the method handling the event. `selecteDOP` will most likely be `null` in the initializer where you're trying to retrieve the value even if the expression can be evaluated without a `NullPointerException` the value is just the initial value and never a value set based on user interaction...

Comment: I stored date using ((TextField)selecteDOP.getEditor()).getText() in my database as a Text.

Comment: I don't recommend doing this. This makes it much harder to write conditions based on the date and even worse the formatter used to be used for the `DatePicker` depends on the locale. You won't get the same results in Germany and in the USA. Using the [`DATE` sql type](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/datetime.html) would be much better and using `PreparedStatement ps` all it takes regardless of locale to use the date would be `ps.setDate(index, Date.valueOf(selecteDOP.getValue()))`.